# How to make a heatmap with more detailed (different) colors to distinguish closer values?

Tags: r, heatmap, levelplot

Code:

```
library("lattice")
n <- (1:10)*10
Dynamic_n <- (1:10)*10
data <- expand.grid(X=n, Y=Dynamic_n)
results <- c(0.74, 0.648, 0.544, 0.457, 0.406, 0.344, 0.327, 0.278, 
                       0.277, 0.232, 0.87, 0.913, 0.919, 0.898, 0.873, 0.839, 0.8, 0.754, 
                       0.703, 0.64, 0.889, 0.927, 0.952, 0.949, 0.93, 0.935, 0.918, 
                       0.9, 0.909, 0.875, 0.871, 0.925, 0.951, 0.958, 0.954, 0.959, 
                       0.958, 0.949, 0.933, 0.94, 0.876, 0.952, 0.944, 0.955, 0.973, 
                       0.965, 0.963, 0.964, 0.968, 0.971, 0.871, 0.932, 0.956, 0.961, 
                       0.955, 0.97, 0.964, 0.973, 0.971, 0.969, 0.887, 0.938, 0.958, 
                       0.974, 0.968, 0.959, 0.967, 0.974, 0.97, 0.966, 0.881, 0.944, 
                       0.961, 0.954, 0.966, 0.961, 0.958, 0.965, 0.979, 0.971, 0.878, 
                       0.927, 0.954, 0.966, 0.967, 0.953, 0.959, 0.973, 0.976, 0.969, 
                       0.868, 0.932, 0.952, 0.965, 0.964, 0.97, 0.964, 0.976, 0.966, 
                       0.974)
data$results <- results

levelplot(results ~ X*Y, data = data, xlab="X",
          main="")
```

Plot

[image]

Because the values in the bottom "row" is much smaller than the other values, the colors in those "other values boxes" are all quite dark and hard to distinguish. What can I do to make such a heatmap that all values can be distinguished albeit certain row has quite different values?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to get out of the heatmap.  Two ideas -scale each row separately (although this loses the relevance of the legend) or transform the values to a different scale (although this can create bias if people are not expecting it).

Comment: @MelissaKey I don't know how to use ```scale``` correctly in my situation, as I want to keep the information of the original values. I think I want to make the spectrum wider so that closer values at 0.9xx can be better distinguished as well.

Comment: From my experience, adding more levels doesn't usually help much, but you are welcome to try.  I'm not experienced with `levelplot`, so perhaps someone else knows how to the code that.  One other idea that might help - flip your color direction.  Our eyes tend to do better at distinguishing light colors than dark, so making lighter colors at the top of the range might allow our eyes to distinguish them more easily

Answer (score 0):

I end up using a different function. Here is my code in case others might be interested in it.

Code:

```
library(circlize)
library(ComplexHeatmap)

data <- structure(c(0.74, 0.648, 0.544, 0.457, 0.406, 0.344, 0.327, 0.278, 
                    0.277, 0.232, 0.87, 0.913, 0.919, 0.898, 0.873, 0.839, 0.8, 0.754, 
                    0.703, 0.64, 0.889, 0.927, 0.952, 0.949, 0.93, 0.935, 0.918, 
                    0.9, 0.909, 0.875, 0.871, 0.925, 0.951, 0.958, 0.954, 0.959, 
                    0.958, 0.949, 0.933, 0.94, 0.876, 0.952, 0.944, 0.955, 0.973, 
                    0.965, 0.963, 0.964, 0.968, 0.971, 0.871, 0.932, 0.956, 0.961, 
                    0.955, 0.97, 0.964, 0.973, 0.971, 0.969, 0.887, 0.938, 0.958, 
                    0.974, 0.968, 0.959, 0.967, 0.974, 0.97, 0.966, 0.881, 0.944, 
                    0.961, 0.954, 0.966, 0.961, 0.958, 0.965, 0.979, 0.971, 0.878, 
                    0.927, 0.954, 0.966, 0.967, 0.953, 0.959, 0.973, 0.976, 0.969, 
                    0.868, 0.932, 0.952, 0.965, 0.964, 0.97, 0.964, 0.976, 0.966, 
                    0.974), dim = c(10L, 10L), dimnames = list(c("10", "20", "30", 
                                                                 "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90", "100"), c("10", "20", "30", 
                                                                                                               "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90", "100")))

# Create a color palette with 100 color levels
my_palette <- colorRamp2(c(0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 0.95, 1), c("white", "red", "pink", "blue", "white"))

# Generate the heatmap
Heatmap(data, 
        col = my_palette, 
        cluster_rows = FALSE,     # Don't cluster rows
        cluster_columns = FALSE,  # Don't cluster columns
        column_names_rot = 0,    # Rotate column names 90 degrees
        row_names_rot = 0,        # Keep row names upright
        heatmap_legend_param = list(
          direction = "vertical", 
          title_position = "topleft",
          at = c(0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 0.95, 1), 
          labels = c("0.3", "0.7", "0.9", "0.95", "1"),
          title = "Key"
        )
)
```

Plot

[image]